# iOS, import JSON file, 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I added JSON file to my Xcode7 project as "Groups", and then I am trying to import and parse it in the following way:

```
    NSString *path = @"events.json";
    NSData *jsonData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                        contentsAtPath:path];
    _privateItems = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                    options:0
                                      error:nil];
```

but it gives me the error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'`

Could anyone please help with solving the issue?

Comment: You need to pass a complete path, not just a filename, to `contentsAtPath` method.

Comment: Yes, that's clumsy. There is no other way of doing it?

Comment: What's clumsy about specifying the full path? How else will the app know where the file actually is?

Comment: Ok, anyway, that's working. Thank you!

Comment: But, then, as long as the app would get deployed on another device, would't it start crashing since the path to the resource would not correspond to the one that is written in the app?